# Error with binman and chrome driver directory (RSelenium)

Tags: r, selenium-chromedriver, rselenium

I am trying to use RSelenium and I am having trouble with binman and finding Chrome drivers.

The RSelenium tutorial I am following told me to running this command to find the Chrome drivers available to me:
`binman::app_dir("chromedriver", check = TRUE)`
But I keep getting this error:
`Error: ~/Library/Application Support/binman_chromedriver app directory not found.`

This command should just return a list of Chrome drivers.

I am on MacOS (v 12.6) and using R studio. I have tried reinstalling both RSelenium and binman neither has helped. I also searched my machine to see if binman_chromedriver directory was installed under a different file path but I found nothing. The tutorial I am following implied that installing RSelenium should be enough to make this command run, but maybe I need to install the driver separately?

I am very new to RSelenium so I don't 100% understand what is doing on under the hood so any tips on how to resolve this issue would be great.